# Extract mask from numpy masked array using a logical expression

Tags: python, numpy, no-data

I am trying to find a way to get the mask from a masked array using only a logical expresion. So if `var` is a masked array, I would like to get the mask by comparing it to a nodata object, None or something similar along the lines

```
>>> var = numpy.ma.masked_array([1, 2 , 3], mask=[True, False, True])
>>> print var == None
... False
>>> print var == numpy.ma.masked
... --
```

What I would like to get

```
>>> print var == ???
... array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

I know I can access the mask directly through `var.mask`, but in my use case I can only evaluate logical operators, such as `numpy.equal`.

Any idea what I could use for `???` to get the mask?

Comment: Are there any limits on what you can put on the right side? For example, can you write a custom class with equality defined as `def __eq__(self, other): return other.mask`?

Answer (score 0):

If the `fill_value` does not otherwise occur in the array, this should work:

```
var.filled()==var.fill_value
```

A masked array has `data` and `mask` (as well as attributes like `fill_value`).  The `data` is 'raw', that is, unchanged from what you supplied when creating the array.  So the only way you can test the `mask`, is to either look directly at the `mask`, or apply the mask to the data, which is what `filled` does.

Stripped down, `filled` does:

```
m = self._mask
result = self._data.copy('K')
np.copyto(result, fill_value, where=m)
```

It makes a copy of the `data`, fills in the `masked` values with the `fill`.

Obviously this is a convoluted way of fetching the `mask`.  But if you can't directly fetch the mask, you have do something like this.

You could use your own `fill_value`.  `masked` `.__eq__` does something like that (fills both sides with 0 and performs a normal `__eq__`.

```
In [416]: var.filled(0)==0
Out[416]: array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Explore the `ma` definition code for more details: 
`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/ma/core.py`